# Adding hostname to log file

Tags: logging, jboss, jboss7.x, nohup

I am currently using JBoss EAP 6.4.0.GA (AS 7.5.0.Final-redhat-21).

Under my log directory, I have server.log and nohup.out.

I would like them to be server-NodeName.log and nohup-NodeName.out where NodeName is the hostname of the OS.

In my standalone.xml file :

```
         <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
            <formatter>
                <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
            </formatter>
            <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
            <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
            <append value="true"/>
        </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
```

logging.properties for FILE ::

```
handler.FILE=org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.PeriodicRotatingFileHandler
handler.FILE.level=ALL
handler.FILE.formatter=PATTERN
handler.FILE.properties=append,autoFlush,enabled,suffix,fileName
handler.FILE.append=true
handler.FILE.autoFlush=true
handler.FILE.enabled=true
handler.FILE.suffix=.yyyy-MM-dd
handler.FILE.fileName=/opt/app/log/server.log
```

Is there any JBoss variable that I can add to change to the log file names ?

Comment: Do you have a system property called `NodeName`?

Answer (score 0):

You can include an expression in the `path` attribute. The one caveat is that the `logging.properties` will be written with the fully qualified path name. There is a log standing [issue](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFCORE-157) open to allow expressions to be written to the `logging.properties` file. There is some concerns around that itself however.

Once the logging subsystem kicks in however the `logging.properties` file will be rewritten and the new path will be used.

If that is acceptable the following CLI command will append the `jboss.node.name` system property to the file name.

```
/subsystem=logging/periodic-rotating-file-handler=FILE:write-attribute(name=file, value={relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir", path="server-${jboss.node.name}.log"})
```

The `nohup.log` is a different story as JBoss EAP as that's an OS thing. It would likely require a modified script of some sort.